# Co-extension of scalars

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

When we have a homomorphism of rings $\alpha :R \rightarrow S$, and if we have a left $R-$module $M$ and regard $S$ as a right $R$-module we can define $Hom_R(S,M)$ and then we can regard this as left $S-$module by doing $sf(s')=f(s's)$, my question is why we define this like this and not like this $sf(s')=f(ss')$, is it because we would need that $r(s.f(s'))=s.(rf(s'))$? There might be something that I am missing from the definitions but I dont see it, thanks in advance.